# Laravel Mail Template with Array

Tags: php, laravel, email, templates

I created a simple mail sender. The problem is [1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJHmB.png here. ı can't add the contacts names at the mail. Plase help me.

My mail send controller.

```
public function sendMail($id) {
    $compaign = Compaign::findOrFail($id);
    $group = Group::findOrFail($compaign->group);
    $contacts = Contact::all()->where('group', $group->id);

    if($contacts->count() <= 0) {
        Session::flash('error', 'No recipients found!');
        return redirect()->route('compaign.index');
    }

    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        $data = [

            'compaign' => $compaign,
            'group' => $group,
            'contact' => $contact,


        ];

        Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->from($data['compaign']->femail, $data['compaign']->fname);
                $message->to($data['contact']->email, $data['contact']->name)->subject($data['compaign']->subject);
        });
    }

    Session::flash('success', 'Successfully sent the campaign');


    return redirect()->route('compaign.index');
}
```

my mail.blade.php

{!!$compaign->content!!}

Comment: Is the issue that you want to be able to pass over the `blade syntax` from a WYSWIG editor instance into the content of the email and have it parsed using the blade syntax again?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry i can't understand

Comment: what wysiwyg are you using?

Comment: @CalinBlaga trumbowyg-editor

Comment: Then I guess you need to do something like this: $('#editor-id').trumbowyg('html', "{!!$compaign->content!!}"); in the blade file. Sure you have to replace #editor-id with your actual textarea id.

Comment: @CalinBlaga thanks but not working

Comment: can you provide a screenshot or the actual code of the blade file?

Comment: @CalinBlaga {!!$compaign->content!!} my problem is only i can't write the names of contacts the mail. Example: 

Hello $name 

Hello Calin 
Hello Şeref  like this

Comment: Sorry but it seems I don't understand what's not working. Maybe provide a clearer explanation.

Comment: @CalinBlaga I want to send multi mail like this. Hello {{name}}, this is your email adress : {{email}}. i want to send this mail my every users.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
Mail::send('mail',array('compaign' => $data), ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->from($data['compaign']->femail, $data['compaign']->fname);
            $message->to($data['contact']->email, $data['contact']->name)->subject($data['compaign']->subject);
    });
```

Comment: it's allready working my problem is only i can't write the names of contacts the mail. Example: Hello $name Hello Calin Hello Şeref like this

Comment: do you need like this $message->from('test@email.com', 'Name') right ?

Comment: No, i need like this: Hello {{username}}, This is your email adress: {{email}}. i want to send multi mail like this.

Comment: you can make your whole template in controller i.e
$message = "Your ".$username."This is your email adress:".$email."

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public function sendMail($id) 
{
    $compaign = Compaign::findOrFail($id);
    $group = Group::findOrFail($compaign->group);
    $contacts = Contact::where('group', $group->id)->get();

    if( ! $contacts->count()) {
        Session::flash('error', 'No recipients found!');
        return redirect()->route('compaign.index');
    }

    $data = [
        'compaign' => $compaign,
        'group' => $group,
        'contacts' => $contacts   
    ];

    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {              
        Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($compaign, $contact) {
            $message->from($compaign->femail, $compaign->fname);
            $message->to($contact->email, $contact->name);
            $message->subject($compaign->subject);
        });
    }

    Session::flash('success', 'Successfully sent the campaign');


    return redirect()->route('compaign.index');
}
```

in blade

```
@foreach($contacts as $contact)
    {!! $contact->email !!}
    {!! $compaign-fname !!} 
@endforeach
```

If not please dump the $compaign and $contacts variables.

Comment: What do you mean by: "Not working"? You don't get the emails displayed, you have an error or...? Have you dumped the $compaign and $contacts variables?

Comment: And it would be nice to place the content of mail.blade.php here.

Comment: i already have a mail.blade.php and i create a campaign and i send mail. i want add {{$name}}to textarea and send mail.

Comment: I know you already have the view file because otherwise you would get an exception but that's not helping at all without knowing what's in there. So the only way I can help you is if you share the "mail.blade.php"  file content.

Comment: " {!!$compaign->content!!} " mail.blade.php